# Carousel Slider when Hover the item it will expand without Overlap other item

Tags: html, jquery, css

[Hover Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUc9E.jpg)

For above html structure

When hover the item, width of this item increase and Other item Won't affect the structure

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://codepen.io/siiivadev/pen/ZErZjOE

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want the item to overlap other items when hovered, but instead its expanding them. The problem here is that you may be increasing the size of the item (width, height) on hover which will affect other elements because I assume the position is relative. What I suggest is to do "transform: scale()" on hover instead on increasing the width or height. It will work the same without affecting other elements. I hope this helps. If not, you can provide the code snippet for better understanding of situation.

Comment: Hi Basit Mir I have attached codepen below i have attached exact output like this https://codepen.io/siiivadev/pen/ZErZjOE